# How to tell number of active users logged into a Django site

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, lamp

Is there a way to find the number of users that are currently logged into a Django site running on Linux? I need to restart the server and I want to make sure there are 'few enough' people that it won't be too much a hassle.

Comment: What CMS are you using?

Comment: This is on Python/Django

Comment: First step: define what you mean by "logged in" for your particular use case.  Once you've got that out of the way, implementation is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

To see what users are logged into Linux, you can use `w` or `who`.

The output of `w` on my machine:

```
USER TTY FROM LOGIN@ IDLE JCPU PCPU WHAT
wesley tty1 :0 Tue12 39:54m 1:34m 0.06s pam: gdm-password
wesley pts/1 :0.0 Tue16 1:38m 0.45s 0.44s ssh user@remoteserver1.com
wesley pts/3 :0.0 Tue16 1:38m 0.49s 0.47s ssh user@remoteserver2.com
wesley pts/5 :0.0 Tue20 0.00s 0.25s 0.03s w
```

The output of `who` on my machine:

```
wesley   tty1         2012-02-14 12:28 (:0)
wesley   pts/1        2012-02-14 16:24 (:0.0)
wesley   pts/3        2012-02-14 16:34 (:0.0)
wesley   pts/5        2012-02-14 20:46 (:0.0)
```

To see which users are logged into an application, such as WordPress or Joomla, will require different, application specific methods, however.

---

Since you're using Django, you will need to programmatically query the `session` model for non-expired sessions. Check out the Q/A titled "[How to get the list of the authenticated users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723052/how-to-get-the-list-of-the-authenticated-users)" over on StackOverflow for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: This is a django, non-specific site. I'm basically looking to infer the number from either open sessions or some other method

Answer (score 0):

How about apache mod_status.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_status.html